# Firefox/Windows - Crashing with Flash Debugger

Tags: windows, flash, debugging, firefox

I use daily the Flash debugger. Lately, after switching to 64 bits Windows, the Flash Player Debug version keeps crashing after showing an alert message.

EDIT:
It seems now it's fixed. The Flash Player Debugger was crashing every timi it throws a warning. I've changed the default timeout  on Firefox as follows:

1. In the address bar type about:config
2. Click on the "I’ll be careful, I promise" button.
3. Type dom.ipc.plugins.timeoutSecs in the Filter text field
4. Double click on the filtered result and change the value to -1

Xanxan!

Comment: 3 years later, still valid. amazing